# Aneni prayer for pregnancy best practice

Tags: tefilla, pregnancy-birth, tehilim-psalms

What is best practice with regards to saying the Aneni prayer by a husband whose wife is in her 3rd month of pregnancy?

Should the prayer be said only once, or daily? 
If daily, then is this only for that month (i.e. stop in month 4) or should it be repeated until the next applicable Aneni (@ 7 months)?

Comment: What is the Aneni prayer? Please put in a link with its text.

Comment: This is the book: [link](http://www.feldheim.com/aneni-special-prayers-for-special-occasions.html)   but from what i can gather the prayer originates from "Avodas Ha-Kodesh" with the prayer saying: "To be recited by the husband when his wife enters her third month of pregnancy"

Comment: another reference says its from Sansan L'Yair by Chida